# how to login from json object in json error

Tags: android, json, android-volley

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static  String LOGIN_URL = "http://172.26.154.132:75";
    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    private Button buttonLogin;
    private ProgressBar loading; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email1);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        loading = findViewById(R.id.loading); 

        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String mEmail = username.getText().toString().trim();
                String mPass = password.getText().toString().trim();

                if(!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()){
                        Login1(mEmail, mPass);

                } else {
                 username.setError("Please insert email");
                 password.setError("Please insert password");
                }

            }
        }); 
    }

    private void Login1(final String username, final String password) {

        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("data");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                            if (success.equals("data")) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                                }
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            buttonLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "error" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }
            })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } 
}
```

**The response:**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "User login successful.",
    "data": [
        {
            "sno": "165",
            "username": "khushboo.iit@gmail.com",
            "user_id_generate": "khushbu@Paswan2018782",
            "password": "25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b",
            "is_verified": "1",
            "hash": "",
            "user_type": "icb_user",
            "user_role": "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please help me donot get data from this

Comment: Please elaborate what problem are you facing?

Comment: Do you mean you are not getting data from the API?

Comment: sir when run this code it give not return value from json object

Comment: on json object which value I passed fro api

Comment: i have confissusion when i request on api which parameter is need on android volley library for json object

Comment: @KinjalRathod yes sir on problem on json object

Comment: Can you post the error log

Comment: no value from data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your API successfully return data then the problem is JSON parsing. JSON data not parsed successfully. Because `"data"` contains an array not a single `String` value.

Try this

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("status");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

        if (success) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            }
        } 

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: one problem is occured when update my android studio my api link not work connection error faild to connect url name

Comment: Didn't get it. Please more details.

Comment: connection Exception

Comment: Check your server is running properly or not?

Comment: happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understood question properly but i think i know what you meant.
As there are two functions one is for success and one is for failure you can handle cases like this..

Use JSONObjectRequest instead of string request, It will return you a JSONObject string instead of a string response. Or You can convert the string into a JSONObject like this

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(response)
```

and then you can parse the jsonObject like this.

```
if(respose.optString("status")==true)
//success
else
//failed
```

If you want to print the error msg which is coming from server... do it like this:

```
error.networkResponse.statusCode
error.networkResponse.message
```

Comment: sir i will try  but it doesn't work i have problem when i request response on json api which parameter is need for excess api

Comment: {
    "status": true,
    "message": "User login successful.",
    "data": [
        {
            "sno": "165",
            "username": "khushboo.iit@gmail.com",
            "user_id_generate": "khushbu@Paswan2018782",
            "password": "25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b",
            "is_verified": "1",
            "hash": "",
            "user_type": "icb_user",
            "user_role": "admin"
        }
    ]
}